# Convert Multivalued map to HashMap

Tags: java, hash-map

I have a `Multivalued map (javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String>)` which I want to convert to regular HashMap so I got below code:

```
private Map<String, String> convertMultiToRegularMap(MultivaluedMap<String, String> m) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (m == null) {
        return map;
    }
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        String qKey = entry.getKey();
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();
        if (values.size() > 1) {
            String val = "";
            int i = 0;
            for (String s : values) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    val += ",";
                }
                val += s;
                i++;
            }
            map.put(qKey, val);
        } else {
            map.put(qKey, values.get(0));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Is there any improvement I can do here? I am using Java7.

Answer (score 7):

The main part of the code is converting the `List<String>` value into a `String` delimited by a comma. Instead of using an external `i` variable, you can use a `StringBuilder` and append the comma or not depending on whether it is empty or not.

Regarding your current code:

- Try to avoid concatenating String with `+`. You should use a `StringBuilder` when necessary.
- You don't need to make a separate code path for the case where the list is empty in the map value: the regular path handles it also.
- You don't need to store the key and the value in local variables.
- It is indeed a very good idea to return a new empty map instead of `null` when the incoming map is `null`.
- If the value stored in the multimap is an empty list, then your code will throw an exception because it tries to access the element 0 when there is no such element.

This would be a proposed code for Java 7:

```
private Map<String, String> convertMultiToRegularMap(MultivaluedMap<String, String> m) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (m == null) {
        return map;
    }
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(',');
            }
            sb.append(s);
        }
        map.put(entry.getKey(), sb.toString());
    }
    return map;
}
```

---

As a side-note, when you'll upgrade to Java 8, this code can be made simpler by using the new [`String.join(delimiter, elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method.

Comment: One case you are missing: If the old stored value was `null`, then the new stored value will be empty string. You might want to preserve null in that case. Otherwise, good review.

Comment: @Pimgd Thanks! Actually, if the old value was `null`, it would throw a NPE at `if (values.size() > 1)` so I guess there are no `null` values.

Comment: Would it? I dunno... all I know is that an empty list would throw for `values.get(0)` with `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for sure. Depends on how the implementation returns `entrySet`.

Comment: @Pimgd Yes, if `entry.getValue();` returns `null` then the code throws at the if just after. And you're right, if the list is empty, there is an exception, thanks, I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for your suggestion. What's the right way to handle point 5? I don't want this code to throw Exception.

Comment: @user1950349 The way I see it, a good way would be not to have this if `if (values.size() > 1) {`. The code for an empty list or a list with some elements should be the same, there should be no special case of an empty list (so it joins point 2). This is what my proposed code is doing: looping over the value of the list; if there is none, nothing is happening.